# Lipschitz implies bounded derivative?

Tags: calculus

Is there any function which is Lipschitz but has an unbounded derivative ? I guess there isn't but I have not found one.

Answer (score 10):

By definition of Lipschitz, $f'$ is necessarily bounded since $|f(x) -f(y)|\le L |x - y| $ which implies that 
$$|g'(x)| = \left|\lim_{y\to x} \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} \right| \le L$$
for all  $x$ (assuming $g'(x)$ exists).

Comment: I believe this also shows that if $f'$ exists and is (uniformly) bounded then $f$ is Lipschitz, correct?

Comment: Yes the condition is sufficient too, in addition to being necessary.

Comment: To be clear, we're assuming that $f$ has codomain $\mathbb{R}$, then?  I ask because the notation $d_y$ suggests a more general context.

Comment: It should be noted that a Lipschitz function need not be differentiable. Example |x|. If a Lipschitz function is differentiable then the derivative is bounded.